# How to set default date of format 'MM/dd/yyyy'

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Here is my code for creating calendar by using Bootstrap datetimepicker:

```
$('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
    minDate: new Date(moment(new Date()).add(0, 'days').toDate()),
    maxDate: new Date(moment(new Date()).add(7, 'days').toDate()),
});
```

Now I want to set default date of calendar to be my custom date, its format is like this '2017-03-30'

How can I convert that to be the same format as format of datetimepicker that I have set before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap datetimepicker uses [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) to manage dates, so:

- You don't need `new Date(...)` and `toDate()` in your `minDate` and `maxDate` option.
- The [`format`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option should be compliant to [moment tokens](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), in your case change it into **uppercase** `MM/DD/YYYY`.

The picker has a [`defaultDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) option, you can use it to set `2017-03-30` as default date, you simply have to [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) it using moment (`moment('2017-03-30')` will be enough since you input is in supported ISO 8601 format).

Note the the datimepicker has [`useCurrent`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) option if you have to default to the current date.

Here a working example:

```js
$('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
  inline: true,
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
  minDate: moment().startOf('day'),
  maxDate: moment().add(7, 'days').endOf('day'),
  defaultDate: moment('2017-03-30')
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The snippet will not work after the `2017-30-17` beacuse the default date will be not included between `minDate` and `maxDate`.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the solution that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Valid formats are documented here:

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format

and from there you can read:

See momentjs' docs for valid formats. Format also dictates what components are shown, e.g. MM/dd/YYYY will not display the time picker.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

So for your particular case it will be:

```
format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'  //(all uppercase)
```

and to set the default value you need to use:

```
defaultDate:
```

The documentation for `defaultDate` is [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```